# Can't filter empty fields in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to get a list of users that have provided an email in my database using Django.

This is my query:
`list(App.objects.exclude(admins__email__exact='').values('admins__email'))`

which strangely excludes everything and gives: `[]`

although when I run: `list(App.objects.all().values('admins__email'))` i can see a list of user emails and NOT all of them are empty:

```py
[{'admins__email': 'example@gamil.com'},
 {'admins__email': ''},
 {'admins__email': ''},
 {'admins__email': ''}, 
 {'admins__email': 'example2@gamil.com'},
 {'admins__email': 'example3@gamil.com'},
 {'admins__email': ''},
 ...]
```

i expect to get this list:

```py
[{'admins__email': 'example@gamil.com'},
 {'admins__email': 'example2@gamil.com'},
 {'admins__email': 'example3@gamil.com'}]
```

ps: somehow I can get the correct list with `list(User.objects.exclude(email__exact='').values('email'))` but in this context, I need to apply some filters to my `App` and therefore I need to get the first query to work.

Comment: What about `list(App.objects.exclude(Q(admins__email='') | Q(admins__email=None)).values('admins__email'))
` it would return list of dictionaries, with non-empty `admins_email` field.

Comment: @SunderamDubey still got an empty list...

Comment: Try to add `annoate` and `distinct` so `list(App.objects.exclude(Q(admins__email='') | Q(admins__email=None)).annotate(email_address=Q(admins__email)).values('email_address').distinct())`

Comment: Thank you @SunderamDubey for your help. i  actually got it working this way: `list(App.objects.filter(admins__email__regex='.').values('admins__email'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working this way:

```
list(App.objects.filter(admins__email__regex='.').values('admins__email'))
```

although I find it odd that `__exact=''` is not working. seems like a Django bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
User.objects.exclude(email__isnull=True).exclude(email__exact='')
```

Comment: as i said in the PS, i need to approach from the `App` model. also i have tried `list(App.objects.exclude(admins__email__isnull=True).exclude(admins__email__exact='').values('admins__email'))` but still got an ampty list.